# Windows freeze after login

Tags: windows, windows-vista, freeze

I have an old machine with Windows Vista - Ultimate Edition which was working just fine until 3 weeks ago, when it started to freeze just after I login to Windows.

What's really confusing me is that if I didn't login and left the machine on the Windows vista login machine, it will not freeze even if I left it for hours and hours. But if I just login it will take anywhere between 1-3 minutes and it will automatically freeze.

I have tried disabling all startup services, programs but no use. I've also tried disabling power saving options but the problem still exist.

I've tried using product like CCleaner to cleanup my registry, temp files but no use the problem still there.

I am doubting that it might be a program / virus or anything but not sure...so can someone please advice me what might be wrong on the machine? how I can possibly trace such weird behaviour?

Comment: How are you able to use CCleaner if the computer freezes when you log into the user profile?  Have you tried to create a new user profile?

Comment: Does it do it if you boot in Safe Mode?  How about if you log in as a different user?

Comment: @Ramhound I am using ccleaner from safemode, yes and it didn't work :(

Comment: @techie007 it works just fine on safe mode, the problem happens only when I start windows normal

Comment: What happened 3 weeks ago?

Comment: 2 approaches here, 1 easy, one tricky:
`1.` Disable processes that start at startup, Autoruns (Sysinternals) or msconfig will do.  The fact it's fine in Safe-mode would suggest a driver or process post login. A quick win might be to disable/uninstall your anti-virus product, that may have updated 3 weeks ago and the sort of product that can cause such issues.

Comment: `2.` More complicated, Shortly after the hang crash the computer with the keyboard - https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard.  You should configure the computer to create a full dump, this will do - https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO31321.html.  This will need to be analyzed with Windbg by someone.  The issue being that as this is a full dump, i.e. all of memory, making it available on a public forum carries some security risk.